# run android and java program from servlet

Tags: java, android, servlets

Can we run the java program and android application from same project in eclipse?
Actually i have a project in which i am running the android application from web/servlet and in same project i have the java program as well. when i run the android unit test then it get worked but stop working the java program and jvm get crashed. it only work when i removed the android from the bootstrap.

Do we have any way to run the both application from one entry point like servlet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make two different projects ? The build is not the same between Java and Android so I think you can't get both working on a same run, however it may be possible to make different Run Configurations to launch either in Java or Android.